# Override dropdown in bootstrap using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've taken this css from this website [sub-menu-drop-down-on-mouse-hover-twitter-bootstrap](http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/sub-menu-drop-down-on-mouse-hover-twitter-bootstrap/)

and this is the code:

```
/*make the menu sub-menu items drop down on mouse hover */
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding: 15px;">
                                        <li>
                                            <input autofocus type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control ignore-max-width" name="mainsearch"
                                                   placeholder="Enter Membership Number..." style="font-size: small;">                                      

                                        </li>

                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-large ">
                                            <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle no-padding" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                <div type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary">
                                                    <span class="home-link glyphicons glyphicons-menu-hamburger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>


                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row col-md-12">
                                                <li class="col-sm-11">
                                                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 5px;">
                                                        <li>

                                                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Left</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Middle</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Right</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Right</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Left</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Middle</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Right</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-link">Right</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>

                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
```

I want to write a custom class so only the dropdown with the that class will display on hover.

Would be good if on hover would work on this tag:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row col-md-12">
```

Can a CSS guru help me out?

Comment: so add your `custom class` and write the style you want

Comment: @Amitsingh I know how to write custom classes in CSS but this particular CSS I don't know how to implement without overriding everything.

Comment: The css you provided is pointing `nav` where is `nav` in your html

Comment: @Amitsingh Nav wraps a search box with a button which is also used else where in the site. I've copied that entire html.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `li.dropdown:hover` to `li.dropdown.yourclass:hover`.

Comment: I've changed my CSS but it doesn't show on hover. I've added the HTML to my post.

Comment: Could you post some more CSS to see what is hidden and what is not? Because right now I don't understand what doesn't work.